# ¿Cuál es la función de un convertView en Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Cuál es la función del parámetro `convertView` que recibe el método `getView` en un **customAdapter** de un **ListView** en Android.

Comment: Esta pregunta es como "Cuál es la función del parámetro parent que recibe la función getView" o "Cuál es la función del parámetro position que recibe la función getView", te sugiero revisar [ask] para realizar preguntas en el sitio, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Este parámetro es usado por el adaptador para reciclar los views que ya no se muestran en pantalla. En otras palabras el último **view** que ya no sale en pantalla es el `convertView` así que nosotros dentro del código podemos usar el `convertView` para llenar los datos de la siguiente forma.

```kotlin
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {

    if (convertView == null){
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)
    }else{
        rowView = convertView
    }
    return rowView
}
```

Como ves en el código anterior estamos reciclando el `rowView` usando el `convertView` en caso de que este no sea nulo, o sea en caso de que haya algún **view** reciclado.

De esta forma si generamos 100 views en el **ListView** no tendremos problemas de memoria y nuestra aplicación irá más rápida.